# As a Mirumoto bushi, should I learn the Spinning Blades Kata?

Tags: l5r, l5r-5e

I am planning on creating a bushi of the Mirumoto niten school for L5R 5e, and I have been surprised to see that the rank 2 Kata that was available at rank 1 was the Iaijutsu Cut: Rising Blade and not the Spinning Blades Style.

After reading the text of the Spinning Blades Kata, I realized that in order to use the Kata, I must not use the Mirumoto school technique (which makes sense after all). But I also realized that it is the case for the Rank 6 Mirumoto Master Technique (which is pretty similar to the Spinning Blades).

So is it worth to learn the Spinning Blades technique by taking into account the following facts:

- Considering it can't be used it alongside the school technique.
- Considering the Mastery Technique is very similar at Rank 6.

As a reminder:

> **Spinning Blades Technique:** (p.180) When performing an Martial Art [Melee or Unarmed] action, you can spend as much opportunities as your target's vigilance to inflict damage with another readied weapon (damage are increased if the target is Dazed).
>
> **Way of the Dragon (School Ability):** (p.68) Whenever you are attacked, you can use a readied weapon to either inflict a malus to your attacker or gain a bonus on your next attack against him. This weapon cannot be used for attack actions until the end of you next turn.
>
> **Heart of the Dragon (Mastery Ability):** (p.68) Once per round, when performing an attack action, you can use an opportunity to perform a Strike action with another readied weapon.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the system, but your 3 questions seem substantially different from one another - especially the last one, which is also primarily opinion-based (there's no way to choose a "best" answer, as all answers would be equally valid). StackExchange policy is to ask one question per post (relevant metas [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts)). I'd suggest editing out your secondary question and asking it separately.

Comment: At the very least I am removing “Can anyone share experience on playing a Mirumoto (5th ed)?” since that is an invitation for social discussion, not a problem with a correct/best solution.

Comment: When you ask "is spinning blades worth it" - what are your character objectives?  If your general objective is character optimization, [please take a look at this meta post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1641/22566) to see how to present that kind of question.  Also, are you asking if the Mastery Technique is a "trap option" in this system?  I think your second question is pointing toward that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of insight, here are my conclusions.

Regarding the fact that you can't use the Way on the Dragon in the same time that the Spinning Blade Style, this is not a limitation per se. You can use the Way of the Dragon to defend, and whenever you have initiative or there is a round where you were not targeted, you can switch to offense and use the Spinning Blade Style. (However, I am still wondering why this Kata isn't in the Mirumoto's ninten curriculum, but that's a separate question/concern).

Regarding the Heart of the Dragon Mastery Ability, here what I understand : the Spinning Blade Technique allows you to deal damage with your off-hand weapon, even if the attack itself doesn't hit (graphically, you are locking your oppoent's weapon with your own blade while your off-hand weapon strikes). You can picture it as opportunities are like successes, but for your off-hand. The Heart of the Dragon, for purpose, allows you to perform two Strikes with a single Attack action, which means that you can perform Katas with it (Striking as Fire or other cool things). Both cannot be used at the same time though (But that's understandable).

Ultimately, Spinning Blade Style is almost completely useless after reaching Rank 6. Depending on how much opportunities you have on your first Attack Check, you *may* be willing to perform a Spinning Blade instead of risking a Heart of the Dragon, but I think the more katas you have, the better the Heart of the Dragon Ability is (after all, we are comparing a Rank 2 Kata with a Rank 6 School Ability).